# cross ratio - is it ordering invariant

Tags: projective-geometry

I want to know if the cross Ratio depends upon the ordering of the points around a particular point .  I am calculating the cross ratio as :

CR = A(1,2,3)*A(1,4,5)/(A(1,2,4)*A(1,3,5)

where A is the area of the triangle formed using the given numbering of the points as coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd denote the cross ratio you compute as $(2,4;3,5)_1$, the cross ratio of $2,4;3,5$ as seen from point $1$. It depends on the *lines* joining $1$ to $2,3,4,5$, so you might as well consider this a cross ratio of concurrent lines, which is dual to a cross ratio of collinear points. The order of $2,3,4,5$ does matter, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/279192/35416) for the effects of changing that order. It does however not depend on the position of the points on these lines. In particular, you can move a point $2,3,4,5$ to the other half of its line, on the other side of point $1$, and you will still obtain the same cross ratio. So depending on what exactly you mean by “ordering of the points”, this should help answering your question.