# Showing there are 6 possible values for the cross ratio

Tags: projective-geometry

If we look at the cross ratio $(x_0 x_1:x_2 x_3) = \lambda$ of 4 points in projective space, I can see that by looking at all possible permutations (24 of them) of the points we can see that only 6 of them give the same cross ratio.

I.e: $\lambda, \frac{1}{\lambda}, 1-\lambda, \frac{1}{1-\lambda}, \frac{\lambda}{\lambda -1}, \frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda}$

Is there a more efficient way to see this rather than calculating all 24 permutations?

Comment: See [this post of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/279192/35416) for a computation of all the 24 permutations, in case you want something to compare the more efficient answers here against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the cross product as

$$ \lambda = \frac{(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_4)}{(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_4)} $$

As we have the permutation group $S_4$ we only need the generators $(12)$, $(13)$ and $(14)$.

Now

$$(12) \lambda = \frac{(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_4)}{(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_4)} = \frac{1}{\lambda}$$
$$(13) \lambda = \frac{(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_4)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_4)} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - 1} $$
$$(14) \lambda = \frac{(x_4-x_3)(x_2-x_1)}{(x_2-x_3)(x_4-x_1)} = 1 - \lambda $$

What we find is that

$$1 \lambda = 1$$
$$(12)(34) \lambda = \lambda$$
$$(13)(24) \lambda = \lambda$$
$$(14)(23) \lambda = \lambda$$

which is the Klein-Four group $V_4$,

So we can write $S_n = V_4 \otimes S_3$

$V_4$ has 4 elements and $S_3$ has 6 elements. The $S_3$ gives the

$$\lambda, \frac{1}{\lambda}, 1 - \lambda, \frac{1}{1-\lambda}, \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}, \frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}$$

Total we have $24 = 4 \times 6$.